# Sequelize - nested where on include?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have this particular code that I want to convert using sequelize logic. I am converting from .NET to Node:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<NotificationAppEntity>> GetPagged(NotificatioAppGetPaggedReq req, Guid userId)
        {
            var res = await Context.NotificationApp
                .Where(x => req.Types.Contains(x.NotificationAppTypeId))
                .Include(x => x.CreatedBy).ThenInclude(x => x.UserPics)
                .Include(x => x.Comment)
                .Include(x => x.Task)
                .Include(x => x.Goal)
                .Include(x => x.NotificationAppType)
                .Include(x => x.NotificationAppUserRead)
                .Where(x => x.Task.ProjectId == req.ProjectId.Value || x.Comment.ProjectId == req.ProjectId.Value ||x.Goal.ProjectId == req.ProjectId.Value)
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedAt)
                .Skip(req.PagingParameter.Skip)
                .Take(req.PagingParameter.Take)
                .ToListAsync();

            return res;
        }
```

Problem is, I don't know why putting an `[Op.or]]` within an include key gives out an error. Here's my current code so far:

```
async getPagged(userId, body) {
    const notificationApp = await db.NotificationApp.findAll({
        where: { NotificationAppTypeId: body.NotificationAppTypeId },
        offset: body.Skip,
        limit: body.Take,
        include: [
            {
                model: await db.User,
                attributes: { exclude: hideAttributes },
                as: 'CreatedBy',
                include: { model: await db.UserPic },
            },
            {
                model: await db.Comment,
            },
            {
                model: await db.Task,
            },
            {
                model: await db.Goal,
            },
            {
                model: await db.NotificationAppType,
            },
            {
                model: await db.NotificationAppUserRead,
            },
        ],
        order: [['CreatedAt', 'DESC']],
    });

    return notificationApp;
}
```

If I placed a `where:` key inside the objects, Sequelize will treat it as `WHERE .. AND .. WHERE .. AND ..` and so on. Is it possible to use `WHERE .. OR .. WHERE .. OR` inside the include? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure this is what you want. Cause I am not familiar with .Net

But...

If you want to put your [Op.or] condition in where like this...

```sql
SELECT *
FROM NotificationApp
left join Task on ~~
left join Comment on ~~ 
where NotificationAppTypeId = (value) 
AND (Task.ProjectId = ProjectId OR Comment.ProjectId = ProjectId OR... )
```

I think this might be work.

```js
async getPagged(userId, body) {
    const notificationApp = await db.NotificationApp.findAll({
        where: { 
            NotificationAppTypeId: body.NotificationAppTypeId,
            [Op.or] : [ 
           {'$Task.ProjectId$' : ProjectId},
           {'$Comment.ProjectId$' : ProjectId},
           ...your conditions
            ]
        },
        offset: body.Skip,
        limit: body.Take,
        include: [
            {
                model: await db.User,
                attributes: { exclude: hideAttributes },
                as: 'CreatedBy',
                include: { model: await db.UserPic },
            },
            {
                model: await db.Comment,
            },
            {
                model: await db.Task,
            },
            {
                model: await db.Goal,
            },
            {
                model: await db.NotificationAppType,
            },
            {
                model: await db.NotificationAppUserRead,
            },
        ],
        order: [['CreatedAt', 'DESC']],
    });

    return notificationApp;
}
```

I find this `$nested.column$` at [this_link](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/eager-loading.html#complex-where-clauses-at-the-top-level)

Comment: haven't seen this in the documentation. Looks like I miss this out, seeing as Sequelize documentation isn't good at naming their sections properly. Thank you! Will check this out in a while